# How to setup path and env so correct Python used

Tags: python, bash, unix, environment-variables

System A has both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 installed.
System B has both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 installed.

I have at top of Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
```

The reason being that python3 compiler must be used. I want to move it between machines but this will fail now.

Answer (score 1):

for me just

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

works fine

Comment: /usr/bin/env: python3: Not a directory
This is on my path
/usr/local/bin/python3.5. This is what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use Virtualenv to setup your python environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your are set on using `#!/usr/bin/env python3.5`, you could create a symbolic link to the  python3.4 version (called python3.5) and then reference that in your script.  So both environments could use the directive `#!/usr/bin/env python3.5`.  Of course, please add a comment somewhere that this is a symbolic link so people are aware of this environment situation.

In fact, I think the `python` in `#!/usr/bin/env python` solution is a symbolic link.